# How do I get text to surround an image?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

I want to place an image in the top left corner of the paragraph, and I want the text to flow beside and underneath it, like you would see in Microsoft Word for example.

Is this possible?

Comment: Use RichTextBox : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee681613(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: @Aybe I just can't find the setting to make the text wrap around the image, I don't even know what that feature is called

Comment: @Aybe actually I think this feature doesn't exist :(

Comment: It does, but ... see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The best I could get was this, it does it on the first line only.

[image]

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
    <RichTextBox VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <Paragraph>
            <InlineUIContainer>
                <Image Source="/Assets/ApplicationIcon.png" Stretch="None" />
            </InlineUIContainer>
            <Run
                Text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi in adipiscing est, quis varius turpis. Duis aliquet fringilla orci a porttitor. Sed posuere, risus ut auctor tincidunt, erat leo pellentesque enim, sit amet tempus mi tellus id nunc. Suspendisse at fermentum erat, vitae viverra nisi. Proin vitae volutpat mauris. Nulla et ipsum non felis commodo sollicitudin. Proin et posuere sem, et aliquet purus. Etiam lacus nisi, fringilla non orci sit amet, semper luctus dolor." />
        </Paragraph>
    </RichTextBox>
</Grid>
```

Windows Phone is missing `Figure` type which exactly does that :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163371.aspx

It might be achievable if reverse-engineering `Run` and/or `Figure` types ...